# Extending continuous and uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

What do you say about the following statement:

1. Let $f\colon(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Then $f$ can be extended to a uniformly continuous function with domain $[a,b]$.
2. Let $f\colon(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function with domain $[a,b]$.

So, I think that 2) is true, will be like add the points $a,b$ to domain used the definition limit, but I'm not sure. And 1) is true, too. But I don't know a good explanation.

Comment: for the second case, you may not be able to extend if the limits are infinite. In the first case, show that those limits cannot be infinite!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then uniform continuity of $f$ allows us to conclude that the sequence $f(x_n)$ is also Cauchy.

The sequences $a_n=a+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n =b-\frac{1}{n}$ are Cauchy, hence so are the sequences $f(a_n)$, $f(b_n)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, these sequences converge to some numbers $f_a, f_b$ respectively. Define the function $\overline{f}:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\overline{f}(a) = f_a$, $\overline{f}(b) = f_b$ and $\overline{f}(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in (a,b)$. Clearly $\overline{f}$ is continuous in $(a,b)$, it only remains to show continuity at $a,b$.

Suppose $x_n\in [a,b]$, and $x_n \to a$. We have $|\overline{f}(x_n) - \overline{f}_a| \leq |\overline{f}(x_n) - \overline{f}(a_n)| + | \overline{f}(a_n) - \overline{f}_a|$. Let $\epsilon >0$, then by uniform continuity, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|< \delta$, with $x,y \in (a,b)$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. Choose $n$ large enough such that $|x_n-a_n| < \delta$, and $| f(a_n) - f_a| < \epsilon$. If $x_n = a$, then  $|\overline{f}(x_n) - \overline{f}_a| = 0$, otherwise we have $|\overline{f}(x_n) - \overline{f}_a| \leq |f(x_n) - f(a_n)| + | f(a_n) - f_a| < 2 \epsilon$. Consequently $\overline{f}(x_n) \to \overline{f}_a$, hence $\overline{f}$ is continuous at $a$. Similarly for $b$.

For the second case, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}$. Then $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, but the domain cannot be extended to $[a,b]$ while keeping $f$ continuous, and $\mathbb{R}$ valued. To prove this, take the sequence $a_n$ above, then $f(a_n) = n$, and clearly $\lim_n f(a_n) = \infty$. If $f$ could be continuously extended to $\overline{f}$, then $\overline{f}(a) \in \mathbb{R}$, which would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. For the second one, consider something like the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{(x+1)(x-1)}$ as a function $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$
2. For the first one, it might just work out. Alternatively, show that if $f$ is uniformly continuous and $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the domain of $f$, then $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence as well. Then pick a Cauchy sequence in the domain of $f$ that goes to $a$, for example.