# Is $\sin(1/x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

The following question was part of my analysis assignment and I was unable to correctly solve it.

> Is $\sin(1/x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

The following reasoning was given by my instructor : Is $\sin(1/x)$ can't be continuously  extended to $0$. So, its not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

But I have a question : why we need to extend Is $\sin(1/x)$ continuously to $0$ when asked domain is $(0,1)$?

I am not satisfied by the reasoning of my instrictor.

So, I am looking for a rigorious explanation here.

Thank you!!

Comment: A continuous function on $(0, 1)$ is uniformly continuous if and only if it can be extended continuously to $[0, 1]$. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/178266/42969.

Comment: Since you require rigor (good for you) I am not allowed to post this response as an answer.  Intuitively, the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of continuity of $f(x)$ at a specific point $x_0$ is affected by $f'(x_0).$  The central difference between continuity at a point and uniform continuity throughout an interval is that you are forced to craft one specific $\epsilon,\delta$ algorithm that will be applied throughout the interval.  That is okay as long as $|f'(x)|$ is **finite** (i.e. bounded).  When it isn't bounded, you've got trouble.

Comment: @user2661923 This is not so precise. A function can be uniformly continuous whereas its derivative is not bounded. Think about $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Your professor was *not* saying "this is the one and only way to show that $\sin 1/x$ is not uniformly continuous". It is quite possible to show it directly from the definition. What your professor is saying is that this is an easy way to see that $\sin 1/x$ cannot be uniformly continuous. Since (as Martin R says), you can show that any uniformly continuous function on $(0,1)$ can be extended continuously to $[0,1]$, but $\sin 1/x$ cannot be so extended, it cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Very good point.  My blind spot was stuck on the idea that the relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ has to be *linear*, which, as your example highlights, is not necessarily true.  It would have been better for me to say, with respect to whether the function has uniform continuity, if $f'(x)$ is bounded, then you are okay.  If it is not bounded, then you *might* have trouble.

Comment: @user2661923 Actually, the fact that the derivative is bounded is equivalent to the fact that the function is lipschitz (for $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions). Of course it implies that the function is uniformly continuous, but the converse is not true.So yes, the way you say it in your last sentence is the correct one :)